# How to avoid a modal to hide buttons and their actions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm a beginner in coding and I have to prepare a POC. I have some issues with a modal. From his creation I can't click anymore on certain buttons I already had. Someone knows how to keep those buttons available even when the modal come up? I can see them but can't click on them anymore (they seemed behind the modal). You can see it on the pic attached.
Buttons are included into a javascript source code that I got back from an open Autodesk API), modal was coding by myself into an html file.

I look around but I found nothing. I also tried to adjust z-index to the modal but nothing happened.

I would like when I create my modal to keep the onclick action and to allow the action itself.

```js
function prepareAppBucketTree() {
  $('#appBuckets').jstree({
    'core': {
      'themes': { "icons": true },
      'data': {
        "url": '/api/forge/oss/buckets',
        "dataType": "json",
        'multiple': false,
        "data": function (node) {
          return { "id": node.id };
        }
      }
    },
    'types': {
      'default': {
        'icon': 'glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign'
      },
      '#': {
        'icon': 'glyphicon glyphicon-cloud'
      },
      'bucket': {
        'icon': 'glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open'
      },
      'object': {
        'icon': 'glyphicon glyphicon-file'
      }
    },
    "plugins": ["types", "state", "sort", "contextmenu"],
    contextmenu: { items: autodeskCustomMenu }
  }).on('loaded.jstree', function () {
    $('#appBuckets').jstree('open_all');
  }).bind("activate_node.jstree", function (evt, data) {
    if (data != null && data.node != null && data.node.type == 'object') {
      $("#forgeViewer").empty();
      var urn = data.node.id;
      getForgeToken(function (access_token) {
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/' + urn + '/manifest',
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
          success: function (res) {
            if (res.status === 'success') launchViewer(urn);
            else $("#forgeViewer").html('Conversion en cours: ' + res.progress + '. Merci de réessayer plus tard.');
          },
          error: function (err) {
            var msgButton = 'Fichier pas encore convertis! ' +
              '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" onclick="translateObject()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> ' +
              'Start translation</button>'
            $("#forgeViewer").html(msgButton);
          }
        });
      })
    }
  });
}

function autodeskCustomMenu(autodeskNode) {
  var items;

  switch (autodeskNode.type) {
    case "bucket":
      items = {
        uploadFile: {
          label: "Télécharger",
          action: function () {
            uploadFile();
          },
          icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload'
        }
      };
      break;
    case "object":
      items = {
        translateFile: {
          label: "Convertir",
          action: function () {
            var treeNode = $('#appBuckets').jstree(true).get_selected(true)[0];
            translateObject(treeNode);
          },
          icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'
        }
      };
      break;
  }

  return items;
}

function uploadFile() {
  $('#hiddenUploadField').click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Navigation bar: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ -------------------------------------------------------------------------->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div id="navigation" class="container-fluid">
      <div id="leftSide">
        <button id="navbaricons" type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="masquer_div('Arborescence')"></button>
        <a href="http://www.overdrive.fr/accueil/" target="_blank">
        <img alt="Logo Overdrive" src="img/logo_overdrive_blanc.png"></a>
        <a id="nom">- bimDrive -</a>
        <button id="navbaricons" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="float: right" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'"></button>
        <button id="navbaricons" type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" style="float: right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MapModal" onclick="masquer_div('MiniMap')"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
<!-- END of navigation bar ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->


<!-- Arborescence Modal -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
  <div class="arbomodal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div class="arbomodal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" data-toggle="tooltip">
          <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" style="float: left" id="showFormCreateBucket" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createBucketModal"></button>Maquettes
          <span id="refreshBuckets" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" style="cursor: pointer; float: right"></span>
      </div>

      <div id="appBuckets" class="modal-body"></div>

    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap and jQuery are you using? [Seems](https://jsfiddle.net/q9gwLdya/) like I am still lacking code.

Comment: The reason the other parts of the screen becomes out of the reach is because there's mask overlaid over them underneath the modal box. Use the devTools of your browser to find its class/id and remove them.

Comment: @BryanHuang if I do that I loose my modal effect and the window modal doesn't come up ahead of the background part, but the background part will be displayed below of the modal...

Comment: Sounds like you need to increase the z-index of your modal popup - if you still can't get it to work replicate your problems on jsfiddle so i can look into them